# Google Maps Android Fragments load last markers

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

i'm using google maps for android with fragments but with problems when change other fragments with navigation.
When i return to the fragment that have markers and map the app draw again all map and markers.
How can i take the control of all this? please help

this is how control change of fragments in activity

```
switch (position){
                case 0:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,mapFragment).commit();
                break;
                case 1:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,searchFragment).commit();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,promoFragment).commit();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,settingFragment).commit();
                    break;
            }
```

And this is how show map in fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    map = new SupportMapFragment();
    transaction.add(R.id.map, map);
    transaction.commit();
    map.getMapAsync(this);

    return view;
}

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    database = new Database(getContext());
    readItems(googleMap); //Show all markers
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the Lifecycle methods such as `onResume`

Look here for more details...https://newcircle.com/s/post/1250/android_fragments_tutorial

More specifically - `onCreateView()` is called only when the fragment is first created. If you override `onResume()` you can update values and markers each time the fragment comes back into focus.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    <Your code here>
}
```

Comment: But when i navigate on fragments allways onCreateView is called or maybe the code i have in the Fragment for invoque the maps need to be in another place

Comment: That is because you are making a new fragment every time. Try using a member variable.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is correct to do but mi solution was to declare the fragments first

and when control with switch i only hide the fragment and 
show the necessary fragment